# Can I choose not to fly?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In Magic: The Gathering, can I choose not to use the "flying" ability of a creature when attacking (so that it can be blocked by non-flying creatures)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you cannot choose for a creature to behave as though it did not have Flying unless a card specifically says that you can.

While Flying is an ability, it is not one that you "use". It is just a fact about the creature, like the fact that it it is Blue or has 3 power (for example).

Answer (score 6):

While murgatroid99 is correct that a creature with flying cannot choose to use its ability, there are ways to remove flying temporarily. These include (taking a few random cards for demonstration):

- [Canopy Claws](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=36410) is an instant that can remove flying until end of turn.
- [Downdraft](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4513) is an enchantment with a similar activated ability.
- [Swooping Talon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=45126) lets you pay 1 mana to cause it to lose flying until the end of turn (which is designed to work with its Provoke ability).
- [Ribbon Snake](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=24571) lets *any* player pay 2 mana to cause it to lose flying until end of turn.

Comment: There's also the opposite approach of giving opponent creatures flying or reach (useful for the context provided in the question of allowing legal blockers).

Comment: True, true. And sometimes they're equivalent processes, but other times maybe you'd prefer one or the other - maybe you want to draw out multiple blockers, or maybe you want to remove flying to protect your creature from Hurricane. But definitely in the context of this question it's a worthwhile consideration.