# Can you attack any creature of your opponents with flying if he can't block it

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say you have a flying creature and your opponent has nothing with flying or reach. Could you attack any one of his creatures you choose?

Comment: I picked the wrong duplicate target, the duplicate should be http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/27039/can-i-choose-not-to-fly

Comment: @Joe Neither of those look like dups. This question isn't really just about flying (though the OP thought it was); the OP is asking about attacking creatures directly.

Comment: There is what the question says, and what the asker needs to know.

Answer (score 8):

No, because you don't attack creatures in Magic; you attack *players* (or planeswalkers), and then the player being attacked can choose to block (or not block) your attacking creatures with their creatures if able.  If your opponent has nothing with flying or reach, they will be unable to block an attacking flyer, and so your flyer will deal damage directly to your opponent.